# Adding Imagemanager Plugins into tinyMce RTE

Tags: php

Anybody know how to add the 'imagemanager' and 'filemanager' plugins into tinyMce..??

I've read the documentation from tinyMCE, but it didn't help.

thx...

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy both manager folders to `\tinymce\jscripts\tiny_mce\plugins\`
2. Put init javascript in your js folder. An example of `tm_init.js` content :

   ```
   var tm_c = {
       script_url : '/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
       theme : "advanced",
       plugins : "imagemanager,paste,searchreplace",
       theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,cut,copy,paste,|,search,replace,|,removeformat,|,insertimage",
       theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
       theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
       theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
       theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
       theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
       theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
       theme_advanced_resizing : false,
       template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
       external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
       external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
       media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js"
   }
   ```
3. Include this `init.js` and `tinimce` in your html

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tm_init.js"></script>
   ```
4. Make the `textarea` a tinymce editor:

   ```
   $("#content").tinymce(tm_c);
   ```